# NumPy 1D array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a NumPy array like:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,0,9,10,11,12])
```

What is the most effective way to select all values except values (in my example is 0) at some  positions?

So I need to get an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I know how to skip the one nth value with `[::n]` construction but is it possible to skip several values using the similar syntax?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you want to skip number at certain positions (regardless of its value), or you want to skip number with certain value?

Comment: I would like to skip numbers ar certain positions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [`np.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
>>> np.delete(a, [4, 5, 10, 11])
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem that I see in np.delete is that it's necessary to create a copy of the array. It can be not efficient. Also the inverted index constructing ([x for x in range(len(a)) if x not in idx]) is not so efficient because of loop or iterator. The size of array in my case can be several millions values which are separated by several symbols --> it's not efficient to check with "if" operator every values. In any case thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only get views (i.e no copy) if the subarray can be indexed with a slice, `a[start:stop:step]`, which isn't your case. A copy will be made regardless, `np.delete` is the fastest way to produce it.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options:

1. If you want to get an index vector that you can use on multiple arrays:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   #your input
   a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,0,9,10,11,12])
   #indices of elements that you want to remove (given)
   idx = [4,5,10,11]
   #get the inverted indices
   idx_inv = [x for x in range(len(a)) if x not in idx]
   a[idx_inv]
   ```

   This output:

   ```
   array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
   ```
2. Use `np.delete`:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   #your input
   a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,0,9,10,11,12])
   #indices of elements that you want to remove (given)
   idx = [4,5,10,11]

   np.delete(a,idx)
   ```

   This outputs:

   ```
   array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
   ```

Comment: Please try to avoid python loops when relating to numpy arrays. `idx_inv` can be computed using `np.in1d` much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boolean array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,0,9,10,11,12])
print a[a != 0]
# Output: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

and you can change `a != 0` to other conditions which result in a Boolean array.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**boolean or mask index array**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,0,9,10,11,12])
>>> a[a != 0]
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Comment: Thank you!But I need to skip the values at some positions. In my example it's "0" (just for example) but it can be any values. So it's not possible to use the boolean or mask array directly like a[a!=0].

Comment: @vitmol, Change the value as you want. For example: `a[(a != 4) & (a != 0)]` or `a[a < 3]`

Comment: Falsetru you proposed to find an index of skipped elements based on value of the element. It's very straightforward and works fine for other situation. In my situation I know which values I would like to skip. (e.g. skip 4,5,10,11 etc). But it's base on position, not based on value. I only need a fast solution to perform such slicing. Thank you for your help!